# How to create a method to move file from one directory to another using Spring Integration File Support?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I am self learning Spring. I want to create a method, whose parameters will be source directory, destination directory, and file name.

```
boolean moveFile(String sourceDir, String targetDir, String fileName)
```

The method may move the file from source directory to destination directory. I have gone through [spring integration file support doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html). Also I have googled for examples, but always get examples where both directories at hard coded in xml file, and the source directory will be watched, and file moved to target directory when new file comes. How can I create the method I am trying to accomplish.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Well, Spring Integration doesn’t provide such a functionality because it exists really as a single method in Java. See `java.nio.file.Files`: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)

> Move or rename a file to a target file.

Here is some samples and explanations: You can find some info here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/files.html

If you still looking into some Spring Integration out-of-the-box solution, the `FileWritingMessageHandler` provides some functionality to copy from one file to another if the payload is a `File`:

```
<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="moveFile"
                                   directory="/destinationDir"
                                   delete-source-files="true"
                                   filename-generator-expression="'foo.txt'" />
```

This way the `FileWritingMessageHandler` performs this logic:

```
if (!FileExistsMode.APPEND.equals(this.fileExistsMode) && this.deleteSourceFiles) {
        rename(sourceFile, resultFile);
        return resultFile;
}
```

Where `rename()` is exactly this:

```
private static void rename(File source, File target) throws IOException {
    Files.move(source.toPath(), target.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Comment: Ok. Then i can provide full source and file names. Could you kindly show me some code to know how it works? I am a beginner in Java and Spring

Comment: See an EDIT in my answer. There is some new link and code snippet for your consideration